# list of weeks with Start and End Day for a given period in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am working on a report and need to pull data on a weekly basis with monthly breakup for a given period.

Here are my requirements

1) I need weekly data for the given period starting from (1.1.2013) to (6.30.2013) with Monthly break up (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc...) (I kind of got a solution for this..)

I am expecting below output.

```
Week1 01.01.2013  01.07.2013
Week2 01.08.2013  01.14.2013
Week3 01.15.2013  01.21.2013
Week4 01.22.2013  01.28.2013
Week5 01.29.2013  01.31.2013 (Week 5 is Partial week)
Week6 02.01.2013  02.07.2013 (First week of Month 2)
.....
```

2) This is my Crucial Requirement,
sometimes I get start date in the mid of the month lets say 01.08.2013  and end date 06.30.2013. In such cases Monthly break would go beyond current month. something like (01.08.2013 to 02.07.2013, 02.08.2013 to 03.07.2013, etc...)
So My output should be

```
Week1 01.08.2013  01.14.2013
Week2 01.15.2013  01.21.2013
Week3 01.22.2013  01.28.2013
Week4 01.29.2013  02.04.2013 (Week 4 goes to Feb Month)
Week5 02.05.2013  02.07.2013 (Month ends on Week 5 )
Week6 02.08.2013  02.14.2013 (1st week of Month 2)
Week7 02.15.2013  02.21.2013
.....
```

I am looking for a SQL query in Oracle.

Any inputs are greatly appreciated.

So far I got below code (I got this from Stackoverflow fourm)

```
select to_char(gen.d,'YYYY "cW"IW')
         , min(gen.d)
         , max(gen.d)
      from (
             select to_date('01.01.2013','DD.MM.YYYY') + level -1 d
               from dual
            connect by level <= 180 -- Instead of End date, I am passing no of days.
           ) gen
     group by
           to_char(gen.d,'YYYY "cW"IW')
         , to_char(gen.d,'YYYY MM IW')
```

Comment: Can you post the code for what you have so far?

Comment: Please find the code I just added.

Comment: What do you expect for output if your starting date is 2013-02-01? (How many weeks and when does the "month" end?) What about 2013-02-02?

Comment: Thanks your Comment, when start date on 2013-02-01 then end of month is 2013-02-28. If Start date is 2013-02-02 then month should end on 2013-03-01.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this. I used the `YYYYMMWW` format for identifying the week.

```
Select to_char(st_dt, 'YYYYMM') || '0' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mon ORDER BY st_dt) week_key,
   to_char(st_dt, 'MONTH'),   
   to_char(st_dt, 'YYYY'),            
   st_dt,
   end_dt,
   ''
from (Select mon, week_num, min(t.dt) st_dt, max(t.dt) end_dt
      from (Select dt,
                   to_char(dt, 'MM') mon,
                   '0' || to_char(dt, 'W') my_week,
                   to_char(dt, 'WW') Week_num
              from (SELECT TRUNC(to_date('01-JAN-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY') -
                                 ROWNUM) dt
                      FROM DUAL
                    CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366)) t
     group by mon, week_num) m
order by st_dt;
```